# Symfony session get array value

Tags: arrays, session, symfony

I'm using Symfony2, and are having trouble getting array values stored in a session, without putting them in a variable or object.

Possible something like:

```
echo $app['session']->get('shop')->get('name');
```

Currently I'm achieving it by doing this, but I would like to avoid it for the cause of simplicity:

```
$temp = $app['session']->get('shop');
echo $temp['name'];
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session object is just a "parameter bag", an object that holds keys & values.

If you want to create another level of that mechanism you would have to instantiate your own bag.

```
$shop = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;
$shop->set('name', 'Fantastic Warehouse');

$app['session']->set('shop', $shop);

// next request
echo $app['session']->get('shop')->get('name');
```